# Love2D does not run in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, environment-variables, love2d

I installed LOVE2D into the program files path, I added it to the environment variables, and I installed LOVE2D Support into Visual studio code. Why are the variable still showing up with the error "Undefined global `love`"? Can someone help me find an answer? This program does run by drag and drop as well[image]

Edit 1: here is the base code itself. I also want to add that it now runs (still does not register love functions) but its when I press Ctrl+S rather than Alt+L. It also runs the file in the main folder as well rather than the one I want to run, being this one (maybe its because the folder is not the main one selected?)
[image]

Edit 2: Here is the code instead. I would just like the answer to this question:

```
function love.load()

    love.window.setTitle("Hello LÖVE")

    love.graphics.setNewFont(24)

end



function love.draw()

    love.graphics.printf("Welcome to LÖVE", 0, love.graphics.getHeight() / 2 , love.graphics.getWidth(), "center")

end
```

Comment: no. Mind showing me that?

Comment: If you type at a command line `love main.lua`, does it run?

Answer (score 0):

To run a love game, you need to indicate only the name of the folder that contains main.lua: `love myFolder`.

Also, love.exe path must be in the Environment Variables

[check here for more details](https://sheepolution.com/learn/book/bonus/vscode)

Comment: Can you copy the relevant info as a quote, inline to the Answer, in case the link becomes broken?